# Draw specific shadow in Android

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm looking for way how to implement specific shadow (like on picture) in my android app Android, with using xml (I can't use 9 patch for this).

[image]

This is white rectangle with the same shadow in all directions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to create a shadow efficiently with XML without using 9-patch image. You can try playing with shapes and gradients, but the result won't look good.

I also did some tests by adding several shapes with transparent borders, but again the result is not good.

Can you explain your situation (why can't you use 9-patch, which is well supported by android).

Comment: I know about situation you described. I can't use 9-patch, because it's one of conditions for that project from customer. 9-patch - the easiest way. Thanks for answer.